# how to get Leading Zeros in integer composed from items on a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am  trying to create a six digit number constructed from serval modbus registers.
I have no idea how modbus register work but was able to map certain numbers to decimal values.

**Example**:

```
'12336': '00', 
'12592': '01', 
'12848': '02', 
'13104': '03',
.
.
.
'14649': '99'
```

I created a dictionary holding the full list of number from 00 to 99, I start reading 3 holdng registers and iterate over them and create an empty list that gets populated with the value  corresponding to the key : value pair in the dictionary then I join them and cast to integer hoping to get the 6 digit number. It kind of works only if i have no leading zeros on my number, however if i do get leading zeros my number gets cut down to where that significant number start.

**My code**:

```
NUMBERS  = {
    '12336': '00', '12592': '01', '12848': '02', '13104': '03', '13360': '04', '13616': '05', '13872': '06', '14128': '07', '14384': '08', '14640': '09', '12337': '10',

    }




def scanned_code():
    code = client.read_holding_registers(1, 3, unit=0)
    r = code.registers
    print(r)
    value = []

    for i in r :
        value.append(NUMBERS[str(i)])
    return value

def numb(lista):
    print(lista)
    res = int("".join(map(str, lista)))
    return res



scan_job = numb(scanned_code())
print(scan_job)
```

Let's  say I have 3 holding registers with the following values: **12336, 13360, 14128** I would spect to generate this number   **000407**. instead I get **407**

**Actual values it get in terminal when executing script**

```
[12592, 13360, 14128]
['01', '04', '07']
10407

[12336, 13360, 14128]
['00', '04', '07']
407
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Fortunately, that syntax has been removed in modern Python.

Comment: @Draconis Good. I'm sure it caused more problems than it solved.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Agreed; it never should have been brought in in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python (and pretty much any other programming language), numbers are stored as binary integers. So the concept of "leading zeroes" is meaningless: to the computer, `123` and `000123` would be stored exactly the same. (And, indeed, a mathematician would say those represent exactly the same value.)

If you want leading zeroes, you should store the value as a string. Just remove the `int` call within your `numb` function.

Comment: Yes I  can see having this as an string, the only issue is i do need the leading zeros, this number gets sent to a system that returns job information  and does require 6 digits in total, but it only recieves interger values

Comment: @victorR If the system wants an integer, it'll accept it without leading zeroes. If it wants leading zeroes, it doesn't want an integer.

Comment: I see.  Thanks '